# Does "generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-107-generic" mean that my kernel is being recompiled?

Tags: linux-kernel

Under Linux Mint 20.1, some updates will print the following (or something similar) in the "Details" window:

> generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-107-generic

Does that message mean that my kernel is being recompiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It's rebuilding the [initial RAM disk](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/initrd.html) used to boot your system.  The Kernel itself is not being recompiled.